# Protect against index out of bounds

Tags: ios, xcode

I am having trouble only executing objectAtIndex if I have values present.

My code:

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSDictionary *results = [json objectForKey:@"d"];

NSString *error = [results objectForKey:@"error"];
NSLog(@"results::%@", [results objectForKey:@"agency"]);
if ( results !=nil)
{
    item = [[results objectForKey:@"agency"] objectAtIndex:0];
    codeItem = [[results objectForKey:@"agency"] objectAtIndex:1];
}
```

It works fine if I have data in the json but if the json comes back like this:

```
{"d":{"success":true,"agency":[]}}
```

It crashes, I know my if statement is wrong but I dont know the correct method to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the value before getting the object:

```
NSArray *agencyItem = [results objectForKey:@"agency"];

if ([agencyItem count] > 1)
{
    codeItem = [agencyItem objectAtIndex:1];
}
```

Comment: `agencyItem != nil` is redundant.

Comment: I added the != nil just because I was not sure about the output, its removed.

Comment: Just to keep in mind that `[somearray firstObject]` and `[somearray lastObject]` are always safe to use; if `somearray` is empty, then these two methods return `nil`.